# use batch file to “read” a text file, “insert” new lines before a string text file

Tags: batch-file, insert

need your help to develop a batch file in order to read / find a string in a text file and insert a new line "before" it;

for instants, change the following text to  (insert "R 100" before Z10)

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
z 10
q 15

a 1
b 2
c 3
R 100
z 10
q 15
```

=============================================================================

i found a similar code and tried to modify it for my need. but it doesn't work!! could you give me  a hint why the following code is not working !!!

```
@echo off
 setlocal

set inputfile=C:\Users\Desktop\test\file1.txt
set outputfile=C:\Users\Desktop\test\file2.txt
    set "start="
    for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (
        if not defined start set "start=1" & break > "%inputfile%"
        if "%%~a"=="z 10" >>"%inputfile%" echo( R 100)

       )>>"%outputfile%" echo(%%a)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several failures in your code - including the deletion of your inputfile.

```
@echo off
set inputfile=C:\Users\Desktop\test\file1.txt
set outputfile=C:\Users\Desktop\test\file2.txt
(for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=  %%a in ("%inputfile%") do (
   if "%%~a"=="z 10" echo R 100
   echo %%a 
))>"%outputfile%"
```

Note: this will skip empty lines.

(I think `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a ...` will also work)